# Get parent class of a certain class

Tags: objective-c, class, inheritance, introspection

Given a class Car that extends the class Vehicle that extends NSObject.

How is it possible to get programmatically the parent class Vehicle from the child class Car in Objective-C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `class_getSuperclass()` function.

```
Class parentClass = class_getSuperclass([Car class]);
```

You need to import `"objc/runtime.h"` in order to use this function.

Also there is `superclass` method on `NSObject`

```
Class parentClass =  [Car superclass];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just send the message superclass. You can then use the macro NSStringFromClass() if you need the name.